# MySQL get same parameters with different key

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

users:

```
id     first_name     last_name
--------------------------------
1      John           Smith
2      Adam           Jones
```

user_planner_tasks:

```
id     moderator     user_id
-----------------------------
1      1             2
2      2             1
```

I would like to display each task from the 'user_planner_tasks' table. While at the same time displaying the first and last name of the moderator and the user with the corresponding id's.

I wish to have something like this:

```
id    moderator     first_name     last_name     user_id     first_name     last_name
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     1             John           Smith         2           Adam           Jones
```

I know I have to use a **JOIN** of some sort but I cannot, for the life of me, figure it out. Any reference would be great!

Comment: that'd be a pivot query, technically, but wouldn't work, as you cannot have multiple fields with the same name in a result set. you could have `fn1, ln1, fn2, ln2, etc...`, but pivot queries are not supported in mysql, and the workarounds get extremely ugly, extremely quickly, and cannot handle arbitrary N-way row->column pivots anyways.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.id,
       t.moderator,
       m.first_name,
       m.last_name,
       t.user_id,
       u.first_name,
       u.last_name
FROM user_planner_tasks t
LEFT JOIN users u
ON t.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN users m
ON t.moderator = m.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT upt.id, 
       upt.moderator, 
       u1.first_name, 
       u1.last_name, 
       u2.id as user_id, 
       u1.first_name, 
       u1.last_name
FROM user_planner_tasks upt
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON upt.moderator = u1.id
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON upt.user_id = u2.id
```

Here you JOIN two times against the same table.

Answer (score 1):

Here you get user and moderator

```
SELECT t.*, u.*,m.*
FROM user_planner_tasks t
LEFT JOIN users u ON t.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN users m ON t.mderator = m.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general SQL JOIN tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

What you would be looking for would be an outer join.

SQL LEFT JOIN Syntax

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

Yours may look like this:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `user_planner_tasks`
ON users.id=user_planner_tasks.user_id;
```

Comment: change column_name(s) in the second example to *